# Google Assistant: Open / continue action on phone

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-assistant-sdk

I'm developing an action for Google Assistant and I was wondering if I could continue an action which I have started on a device without a screen (e.g. Google Home) on my mobile phone.

E.g. I ask Google Home to search for a good hotel in New York and when it tells me the result I maybe want to visit the corresponding website on my phone. Another example would be: I'm ordering pizza and for the payment process I would have to authenticate via fingerprint / password on my mobile.

Does anybody know if that is / will be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I guess it is possible. It depends on how better you write the webhook for the application.

For this example:
When you ask Google Home to search for a good hotel in New York, keep in mind to make a follow-up intent if the user is asking to check for more details of that hotel, like phone number, or email or other contact details.

In webhook, make an action for this follow-up intent which is to be triggered.
And in the response, call the *getHotelDetail()* function, which would be a user defined function.

**Here is a demo code to understand:**

```
def getHotelDetail(hotel):
   # get all the hotel details using an API or JSON
   # return hotel-details

def processRequest(req):
    # if req.get("result").get("action") == "follow-up-hotel-details":
    #     data = getHotelDetail()
    # else:
    #     return {}
    # res = makeWebhookResult(data)
    # return res

def makeWebhookResult(data):
    # return whatever you want to display/speak as per the 
    # processRequest(req)
```